# How do I put 2D arrays from a queue into another 2D array based on a condition? C#

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, queue, 2d

I have a task based on Tetris formations that I have to put into a queue and then from the queue (if the condition applies) put the formation into a 2D array, with the most optimal filling of the array.
I made the formations from 2D arrays and put them into a queue, but I don't know how to get the formations from the queue to the 2D array. The condition which determines if a formation gets into the 2D array is if there is enough space for it. If there isn't, the formation should be enqueue()d to the end of the queue to be used again later.

```
int[,] I1 = new int[4, 1] { { 1 }, { 1 }, { 1 }, { 1 } };
int[,] I2 = new int[1, 4] { { 1, 1, 1, 1 } };
int[,] Z1 = new int[3, 2] { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 }, { 1, 0 } };
```

etc.

These are int this queue:

```
Queue<int[,]> myqueue = new Queue<int[,]>();
myqueue.Enqueue(I1);
myqueue.Enqueue(I2);
myqueue.Enqueue(Z1);
```

And I tried copying them into a 2D array like this:

```
int[,] Drawer = new int[10, 20];
for (int i = 0; i < Drawer.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Drawer.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        while (Drawer[i,j]==0&& myqueue.Count >0)
        {
            int[,] dequeued = myqueue.Dequeue();
            for (int k = 0; k < dequeued.GetLength(0); k++)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < dequeued.GetLength(1); l++)
                {
                    Drawer[i, j] = dequeued[k, l];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. I also thought about not exactly copying the item into the array, but rather just filling the array with the appropriate amount of 1's based on the item from the queue.
(I edited the code and changed the Hungarian variables to English and added a condition so it won't be an infinite loop. Also the Drawer[,] array is a matrix that's supposed to display a drawer that contains the elements, like an automatic tetris that fills the whole matrix without leaving any empty space. )

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure about your question. You also doesn't provide the information about **Fiok** (the data structure etc).

But i found these code pretty odd :

```
while (Fiok[i,j]==0)
        {
            int[,] kisorolt = sor.Dequeue();
            for (int k = 0; k < kisorolt.GetLength(0); k++)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < kisorolt.GetLength(1); l++)
                {
                    Fiok[i, j] = kisorolt[k, l];
                }
            }
        }
```

your **while** statement will gives you infinite loop because you didnt change **i** or **j** on your code (so if Fiok[i,j] is 0, then you will **dequeue** your **queue** for infinite times and then eventually crash your program because you are **dequeue-ing** an empty **queue**) , so I think what you mean is **if** statement instead of using **while**

```
if (Fiok[i,j]==0)
{
      int[,] kisorolt = sor.Dequeue();
      for (int k = 0; k < kisorolt.GetLength(0); k++)
      {
          for (int l = 0; l < kisorolt.GetLength(1); l++)
          {
              Fiok[i, j] = kisorolt[k, l];
          }
       }
}
else
{
   //put any else statement
}
```

I already tested your code, the output is :

```
 11000000000000000000
 00000000000000000000
 00000000000000000000
 00000000000000000000
 00000000000000000000
 00000000000000000000
 00000000000000000000
 00000000000000000000
 00000000000000000000
 00000000000000000000
```

Comment: I edited my question so it's easily understandable and swithed any Hungarian variable names to Englesh. Also added another while condition so it doesn't create an infinite loop. I tried it with if as you suggested but it gives the same result.

Comment: I already edited my answer abit, could you please post the output expectation with your code? Thank you @akiron111